# Where I can find all settlement boundaries for United Kingdom?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

I'm looking for a dataset containing settlement boundaries for United Kingdoms.

In short example I'm looking for a dataset that would allow me to draw something like the following (orange line):

[image] 
<sup>[(source)](https://www.roselandplan.org/uploads/2/1/4/5/21457108/gerrans-portscatho_conservation_area_and_settlement_boundary_a4p.pdf)</sup>

Comment: Are you looking for something along the lines of cadastral data?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140063/no-cadastral-maps-in-the-uk-solutions-alternatives-for-a-methodology may or may not be helpful

Answer (score 1):

[Settlement boundaries](https://www.herefordshire.gov.uk/download/downloads/id/3711/guidance_note_20_guide_to_settlement_boundaries.pdf) are defined by local authorities (or national park authorities, within national parks) as part of the processing of granting permission for new or adapted buildings. However, [the process used to define them varies in different areas](https://www.southdowns.gov.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/TSF-05-Settlement-Boundary-Review-2017-Update-Background-Paper.pdf) and [not all settlements will have a defined boundary](http://spp.conwy.gov.uk/upload/public/attachments/448/BP8_Hierarchy_of_Settlements_and_Settlement_Boundaries.pdf), so you should not trust that they are consistent across areas.

There doesn't appear to be a national dataset of settlement boundaries, probably because central government does not need the information so would not benefit from collecting it from local authorities. Some local authorities have [released settlement boundaries on data.gov.uk](https://data.gov.uk/search?q=settlement+boundaries) but they are often in different formats and not all are available for download.